# Overloaded `!=` operator in custom iterator class is not working properly

Tags: c++, generics, iterator

I am creating template matrix class and right now I am implementing iterator class to iterate through one column (this iterator class is inside my `Matrix<T>` class).

```
template <typename P, typename V> // "P" - PointerType; "V" - ValueType
class V_Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
private:
    P itData_;
public:
    size_type w; // width of the matrix
    size_type h; // height of the matrix
public:
    V_Iterator(P d) : itData_(d) { }

public:
    V& operator*() const {
        return *itData_;
    }
    /////////////////// BUG /////////
    V_Iterator<P, V>& operator++() {

        itData_ += w;

        return *this;
    }
    V_Iterator<P, V>& operator= (T value) {
        *itData_ = value;
        return *this;
    }
    P operator->() {
        return itData_;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const V_Iterator& lhs, const V_Iterator& rhs) {
        return !(lhs.itData_ != rhs.itData_);
    }
    friend bool operator!=(const V_Iterator& lhs, const V_Iterator& rhs) {
        return !(lhs.itData_ == rhs.itData_);
    }

    V_Iterator<P, V> begin(size_type column) { return V_Iterator<P, V>(itData_ + column); }
    V_Iterator<P, V> end(size_type column) { return V_Iterator<P, V>((itData_ + column) + 1 + (h - 1) * w ); };
};
```

My problem is that when I am iterating using my iterator:

```
Matrix<int> m (5, 5);
for (Matrix<int>::viterator vit = m.v_begin(0); vit != m.v_end(0); ++vit) {
    cout << *vit << " ";
}
```

it never stops because `!=` is never triggered. However if in overloading `++` operator is this code instead of one I already posted

```
V_Iterator<P, V>& operator++() {
    ++itData_;
    return *this;
}
```

It is working completely fine.

Here is more code inside my Matrix class:

```
public:
V_Iterator<T*, T> m_viterator_;
V_Iterator<const T*, const T> m_const_viterator_;

typedef V_Iterator<T*, T> viterator;
typedef V_Iterator<const T*, const T> const_viterator;

viterator v_begin(size_type column) { return m_viterator_.begin(column); }
viterator v_end(size_type column) { return m_viterator_.end(column); }
const_viterator cv_begin(size_type column) { return m_const_hiterator_.begin(column); }
const_viterator cv_end(size_type column) { return m_const_hiterator_.end(column); }
```

`Matrix` class constructor:

```
Matrix(const size_type& width, const size_type& height) :   width_(width),
                                                            height_(height),
                                                            data_(CreateMatrix(width, height)),                                                                m_viterator_(*data_),
                                                            m_const_viterator_(*data_) {

    m_viterator_.w = width_;
    m_viterator_.h = height_;
    m_const_viterator_.w = width_;
    m_const_viterator_.h = height_;

    // fill the created matrix with default values of "T"
    for (Matrix<T>::iterator_type it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it)
        *it = T();
}
```

I was trying to figure out what is wrong but to me everything seems ok.

Comment: Where and how is the `w` member initialised? The buggy behaviour would correspond to it being 0.

Comment: BTW, have you stepped through the code in a debugger? What has that told you?

Comment: `w` is initialised in `Matrix` constructor (I edited my question).

Debugger doesn't show any errors or warnings.

Comment: Debuggers don't show errors or warnings. The debugger lets you see where the control flow goes, inspect variables along the way etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator returned by the `begin()` and `end()` member functions does not have `w` and `h` initialised. You set them in the `m_viterator` member, but the member functions `begin()` and `end()` of the iterator class return an iterator initialised from the `itData_` member only, which leaves `w` and `h` in the newly created iterator uninitialised.

Comment: Your answer is completely right. But also @Sam Varshavchik pointed out errors which were partially causing bad behaviour. If I could I would split accepted answer between you two. Unfortunately I can't and since without your answer I would still be experiencing crashing errors I chose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it's being pointed out in the comments, it's not shown how the `w` member gets initialized. However, I also spotted something else. I'm going to assume that the rest of the code that's not shown is going to initialize `w` correctly. Let's look at how you defined begin() and end().

```
V_Iterator<P, V> begin(size_type column)
{
     return V_Iterator<P, V>(itData_ + column);
}

V_Iterator<P, V> end(size_type column)
{
     return V_Iterator<P, V>((itData_ + column) + 1 + (h - 1) * w);
}
```

So, it looks to me like the distance between begin(n) end end(n) or end(n)-begin(n) is:

```
(itData_ + column) + 1 + (h - 1) * w - (itData_ + column)
```

or

```
1 + (h - 1) * w
```

You have stated the problem as follows: when your ++ operator keeps advancing the iterator by `w` each time, the loop iterating from `begin` to `end` will never compare equal to the ending iterator value.

Of course not, because the distance between them will never be an even multiple of `w`!

Comment: ... and I'm going to guess that the correct definition of end() should be (itData_ + column) + h*w. Just a guess. Keep in mind that with traditional iterator semantics, the ending iterator does NOT point at the last element in the iterator's sequence, but at the next element after it.